# Python: How to run a function within another function in the same class suppressing the other function output

Tags: python

I am coding a class called `BiVAR` in that class I have a function called `ResiPlot` that plots a figure. However, in that function, I have defined a variable that is known as `self.resi`. In that particular class, I have another function called `hzTest`. In this function, I am not interested in the plot or the print of the function `ResiPlot`. All I need is to make sure that `self.resi` has been defined.

Therefore, what I am actually looking for is how to define `self.resi` in the function `hzTest`. i.e. calling the function `ResiPlot` supressing its figure or any printed output.

My code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt, subprocess
# Calling built-in functions from R
Rsummary = robjects.r['summary']

class BiVAR:

    def __init__(self, df, restrict=0): # Initialize when created
        self.data = np.array(df.values, dtype=float) # self is the new object
        self.isrestricted = restrict
        if self.isrestricted ==0:
            self.Model= VAR(self.data)
        else:
            p = int(input("Since, you want a restricted model please enter the lag p: "))
            self.p=p
            if p==0: p=1
            t= Rvars.VAR(self.data, p, type='const')
            self.Model= Rvars.restrict(t,method = "ser")
    def BestLagAic(self):
        if self.isrestricted==1: 
            print('Sorry this can not be excuted since you chose the model to be restricted')
        else:
            R=self.Model.select_order(15)
            return R['aic'] # Split string on blanks
    def Fit(self, *parameters, **keyword_parameters):
    # This function allows you to specify the lag variable. If not specified it will use the p value you previously 
    # give it for the restricted VAR model otherwise it will use the best lag based on AIC 
        if self.isrestricted ==0:
            if len(parameters)==1:
                p=parameters[0]
                results = self.Model.fit(p)
                print(results.summary())
            elif len(parameters)==0:
                p=self.BestLagAic()
                results = self.Model.fit(p)
                print(results.summary())
            else:
                print('You included so many unrequired variables')
        else:
            p=self.p
            t= Rvars.VAR(self.data, p, type='const')
            t1= Rvars.restrict(t, method = "ser")
            H=str(Rsummary(t1))
            start = H.find('VAR Estimation Results:') + 23
            end = H.find('Roots of the characteristic', start)
            pvalue=H[start:end]
            start1 = H.find('Estimation results for equation') + 31
            pvalue1=H[start1::]
            print(pvalue+pvalue1)
    def ResiPlot(self, *parameters):
        # This function plots the residuals when fitted with a VAR(p) model
        if self.isrestricted ==0:
            if len(parameters)==1:
                p=parameters[0]
                results = self.Model.fit(p)
                resi=results.resid
                self.resi=pd.DataFrame(resi, columns=['Bond-Resi','Equity-Resi'])
                pd.DataFrame(resi).plot()
                plt.show()
            elif len(parameters)==0:
                p=self.BestLagAic()
                results = self.Model.fit(p)
                resi=results.resid
                self.resi=pd.DataFrame(resi, columns=['Bond-Resi','Equity-Resi'])
                pd.DataFrame(resi).plot()
                plt.show()
            else:
                print('You included so many unrequired variables')
        else: 
            t= Rvars.VAR(self.data, self.p, type='const')
            t1= Rvars.restrict(t, method = "ser")
            t2=t1.rx2('varresult').rx2('y1').rx2('residuals')
            t3=t1.rx2('varresult').rx2('y2').rx2('residuals')
            resi=pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((np.array(t2), np.array(t3))), columns=['Bond-Resi','Equity-Resi'])
            self.resi=resi
            pd.DataFrame(resi).plot()
            plt.show()
    def hzTest(self):
        print('This is the Henze-Zirkler Multivariate Normality test applied on the residuals of the fitted model')
        subprocess.call('self.ResiPlot')
        MVNresult =MVN.hzTest(self.resi, qqplot = 0)
        np.array(MVNresult.slots[tuple(MVNresult.slotnames())[1]])[0]
```

Comment: The `subprocess.call` line looks very suspicious.

Comment: @DavisHerring it did not work. I do not really know what to do. I am new to python. So if I am using it wrong please help me.

Comment: I can't fix everything in comments, but if you want to call `self.ResiPlot()`, you just write _exactly that_.  `subprocess` is for calling other _programs_, not your own functions.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thank you so much for this. but when I do so the plot appears which I do not want. Are you aware in any way how to call a function without plotting its output?

Comment: Did you read my answer?

Comment: yes, but please do excuse my unawareness,  I do not understand your answer

Comment: @DavisHerring for example you mentioned that "just call the computation function in different contexts, " how to do so here in python?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155014/discussion-between-davis-herring-and-rsc05).

Answer (score 0):

You need (a simple version of) [multitier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).  Don't have the functions that compute things also ask the user for their inputs and plot their results.  Then you don't have to "suppress the other function's output"; you just call the computation function in different contexts, some of which produce user-visible output from it and some of which don't.

Comment: for example you mentioned that "just call the computation function in different contexts, " how to do so here in python?

Comment: Trivial example: instead of `def square(): x=float(input("sqr>")); s=x*x; print(s)` write simply `def square(x): return x*x` and, somewhere else (the _client_), `x=float(input("sqr>")); print(square(x))`.  Then the client can choose where `x` comes from and whether and how to display the result.  (This is not at all about Python: this is just sane code design.)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, but this is not what exactly I am looking for

Comment: No offense meant _at all_, but the point of this conversation is that you [don't actually know](http://xyproblem.info/) what you are looking for.  "Suppressing output", while in some cases possible, is a _terrible_ idea when redesigning the callee is a possibility.

Comment: Maybe you are right I better change the design of the class so that I don't have to call a function within a function